# Choosing number of hive Buckets

Tags: hive

How to decide how many buckets should be created while creating a new table??

I came across below answer,

> buckets = (x * Average_partition_size) / JVM_memory_available_to_your_Hadoop_tasknode

But this solution will work only when you have a partitioned table. My table dont have any partitions and it should contain only buckets without partitions?

Regards,
Prabu

Answer (score 0):

Just use the table size instead of the average partition size. That formula is based on the amount of data in a INSERT job: in case of a partitioned table, you'd have one per partition, but in a non-partitioned table you'd only have one.

Comment: Thanks Roberto,

But could you please help me to understand what 'x' means here?

Comment: have a look at the original email where you got the formula from : http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201204.mbox/%3C1335253604.34013.YahooMailNeo@web121204.mail.ne1.yahoo.com%3E  :
> I call x (>1) the "factor of conservatism". Higher x means you are being
> more conservative by having larger number of buckets (and bearing the